# Using Socket.io in different parts of the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, socket.io

everybody.
Here's the thing: how can I process several events in different parts of a file? (react)

Example:

```js
//socket.ts
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:5000';

const socket = io(SERVER_URL, {
    autoConnect: true,
});

export default socket;
```

```js
//File1.tsx
     useEffect(()=> {
        socket.on('message', (data: {message: IMessage}) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
        return () => {
            socket.off('message');
        }
    }, []);
```

and it's work fine, but:

```js
//File2.tsx
     useEffect(()=> {
        socket.on('message', (data: {message: IMessage}) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
        return () => {
            socket.off('message');
        }
    }, []);
```

and it's don't work

Events are coming in, but everything falls into the first. And when I just change the name of the event (on the server too), everything works fine.

Q: Is it possible to organize processing of several events with the same name?

Comment: It is possible. Multiple components can listen for the same socket.io event.
Where is the `socket` from in File1 and File2?

Comment: in file socket.ts